# CouchDB, storing small redundant information

Tags: couchdb

I have to store many informations related to products. On of them is the price and I need to store him, and all of its update.

What is the best practice for a nosql database

Storing:

```
{
  "_id": "price:usd:book:<timestamp>",
  "price": "1"
},
{
  "_id": "price:usd:book:<timestamp>",
  "price": "2.1"
}
```

or

```
{
  "_id": "price:usd:book",
  "price": { "<timestamp>": "1", "<timestamp>": "2.1" }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One of my first reads about recommendations about CouchDB usage was https://github.com/eHealthAfrica/couchdb-best-practices#document-modeling

In your case, if you have a single document that is being updated with the price history, you will get a big document that has many revisions. Every update of this document should keep part of his history and this will have some impact in terms of storage. The replication process is also affected by the number of revisions created for a document.

One single document is also more prone to be affected by conflicts that you have to manage.

If you have many small documents that are not updated, all the previous problems are lessen.

In any case you should consider your business case to determine which of the both approaches better suits for you.